# How to fix setting Android display brightness to 0%

Tags: settings

I have a Windows Mobile phone(HTC Tilt 2) and put Android on it(on the SD card only). When I was messing around with some stuff I accidentally set the display brightness of Android to 0%. So now nothing will ever show up on my screen.How can I fix this without doing a clean install of Android?

Answer (score 4):

Is it the case that you can't see anything at all, or is it just really, really dark at the moment? Most LCD screens will show something faintly, even without a backlight, if you can get them in the right light.

If you can see something then the easiest way to turn the lights up (if you're using Android 1.6+) is to add the Power Control widget to the home screen and then tap the far-right button on the Power Control Bar, this should turn the brightness to half and then full, and you should be able to get to the rest of your settings then.

Comment: Marking this as the answer.. I couldn't actually see anything on the screen though but I already had a brightness widget thing on my home screen and the touch screen works with the screen off so I just had to push around until I found it.

Comment: @Earlz: Try shining a really bright flashlight to the screen (the brightest you can get). If the problem is with too low brightness, but the LCD is still filtering the lights, then you should be able to get faint images by shining a strong light.

Answer (score 0):

Use Apk 1.3 (PC) to access tablet and screen shot shows what is in the screen. Keep refreshing screen shot as you press tablet options.

Mike M.

Comment: A link to the program mentioned would be good.